# Can a certain overloaded constructor, show certain overloaded methods?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a class with both a overloaded constructor and a overloaded method.

If I initiate the class with parameters, the idea would be that I then didn't need to fill this information into my method. But as things grow it can get a bit confusing.

I wanted to know if there is a way of either telling C# or Visual Studio not to show the method in the IntelliSense if a certain constructor is called, hopefully in a clean and neat way without any "hacks".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "not to show the method"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't change the behavior of IntelliSense that way.

The issue you're facing is actually a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) regarding your class design.

If you have certain methods that aren't of any use unless a given constructor was used, you should probably **split the class** so that the different functionality is clearly delineated.

It might make sense to have a base class of the common behavior and subclasses for each of the different types of constructors. This would effectively do what you're asking for, and follow proper object-oriented design.